# Организация проекта (импорты, модули)

Tags: golang, golang-struct

Недавно начал изучать Go и после написания небольшого проекта решил попробовать залить его на Google Cloud Platform.
Собственно начал встречаться с проблемами, которые вызывали вопросы еще в момент написания...
Проект содержит такую структуру:

```
my-project
 handler/
 model/
 main.go
```

Соответственно в handler есть импорты на model.
Изначально я использовал локальные пути типа:

```
import "../model"
```

Что уже начало вызывать некоторое отторжение...
При первой попытке деплоя на GCP, он мне успешно сообщил, что такое не съест и надо менять пути, я загнал ему адреса из репозитория на gitlab и опять у меня сомнения по поводу такого пути...
Ну собственно дальше я столкнулся с проблемой, что он не может заимпортить сторонние библиотеки, поскольку проект лежит не в $GOPATH... и возник вопрос, а как вообще правильно надо делать?
На текущий момент я имею:

1. Импорты идут из репозитория gitlab, как быть с локальной разработкой, чтобы подтянуть свои изменения? менять путь на локальные <-> обратно?
2. Почитал про концепцию модулей, но все примеры указывают на использование отдельных репозиториев, можно ли их использовать в этом же проекте и как?

Answer (score 0):

Использую [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep), все зависимости хранятся в папке vendor, и да проект нужно перенести в $GOPATH

Answer (score 0):

Используйте GOPATH для всего. Модули нужны для зависимостей, их версий. Если Вам не нужно решать эту проблему, то модули Вам не нужны. К тому же они пока ещё экспериментальны, хотя и работают без проблем.

1. Качаете форк проекта в GOPATH с помощью `go get` как обычно.
2. На место проекта ставьте символическую ссылку на форк.
3. Работайте с форком как обычно.

Например, есть проект `example.com/company/pro` и Вы форкаете его в `example.com/user/pro`. И качаете форк себе в `$GOPATH/src/example.com/user/pro`. При этом делаете символическую ссылку

```
$GOPATH/src/example.com/company/pro -> $GOPATH/src/example.com/user/pro
```

Все пути ссылающиеся на `example.com/company/pro` будут перенаправлены по символической ссылке на форк.

Ничего удобнее и проще я не знаю. При этом вся работа выполняется в GOPATH.

---

Может быть с модулями и проще. Но я не в курсе.